# Help finding a 90s cartoon episode about a planet of reptile-like aliens living in virtual reality

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

An episode (of this Western-style animation TV show) was set on a planet of alien creatures living in a virtual reality world where they could make themselves more attractive and their barren planet look more beautiful. Then one day this VR program was switched off some how and the alien creatures were practically paralysed, seeing each other as they really were for the first time.

I also recall there being a scene at the end with humans (one male for sure) observing the scene in total disbelief at how these creatures were living so fully immersed in their VR world and totally blind to their actual reality.

The episode ended, I believe, on a note of hope as the creatures now had to learn to live in the real world.

The episode was in a hand drawn-style typical of Western 90s cartoon series like "Gargoyles," "Exosquad," "X-Men," and "Batman: The Animated Series." I watched it on Channel 5, Singapore's free-to-air English-language channel, in the 90s. We never dubbed American tv shows that were in English so I'm pretty certain that this episode was an American production.

Comment: What were some of the other episodes about?

Comment: If you have a few minutes to spare, consider having a look at this [checklist about _"how to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question"_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) to help you remember other important details, and [edit] them in the question.

Comment: Oh gosh, I really can't remember anything but that one episode. It seems like a dream but I know it's not. I watched this episode on tv as a kid in Singapore in the 90s. We never had any shows dubbed so I'm certain that this was an American production.